# How to fix this error with yfinance downloading data

Tags: python, dataframe, yfinance

I've been using yfinance for a while. When I went on holiday downloading data with yfinance and pandas_datareader stopped working for me. I guessed it was caused by something to do with a different connection. When I arrived back from holiday I still had issues with my code that I've used before without issues. I don't understand the error message and would appreciate if anybody could help resolve the issue.

This is some basic code:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt

start = dt.date(2020,1,1)
end = dt.date(2021,1,1)
ticker = 'AAPL'
df = yf.download(ticker,start,end)
print(df)
```

This code has worked for me in the past however I now receive the following error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/multitasking/__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 168, in _download_one_threaded
    actions, period, interval, prepost, proxy, rounding)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 183, in _download_one
    rounding=rounding, many=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 157, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Update to the latest version will help. 0.1.63

Comment: Could you please let us know which IDE you are using? However, try reinstalling yfinance and execute this code. its working for me.

Comment: @PrantaPalit Was using default IDLE IDE. Also how do I update yfinance?

Comment: @r-beginners Do you mean update python or update yfinance?

Comment: upgrade `yfinance`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try reinstalling/upgrading `yfinance` and execute this code. its working for me.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade yfinance
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with the help of PrantaPalit and r-beginers from their comments. I updated yfinace by updating python with:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade yfinance
```

The code seems to be working fine now. Thanks